# What is the significant of multiple account in an ethereum Wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

What is the significant of multiple account in an ethereum Wallet?
 I have found same question in the below URL
[What is the purpose of multiple addresses in a wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/what-is-the-purpose-of-multiple-addresses-in-a-wallet)

From the answer it is clear that multiple account is there in ethereum for maintainability purposes. I am wondering is there any other advantages of having multiple account within the same wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer to the question you pose, here are several reasons one might have multiple accounts:

- To decrease the risk of any single account being compromised by a third party
- To separate funds for specific purposes
- To increase anonymity (e.g. by creating a new account every time you receive Ether)